# How to create a big circle composed from small circle?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, draw

Is there any way to create the following picture in latex code?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Search http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf for the word "necklace" as a start. And there is a "Graph Drawing Library
`circular`" which should do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one quick idea with `automata`. You will find many other approaches in the pgf manual and on this site.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0:2) arc (0:360:20mm);
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
    \node[state,fill=white] (c_\i) at (-360/10 * \i+126:2cm) {$C_{\i}$};
      }
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Iuli You are very welcome.